# Why does the acceleration of a cart change when the mass at the end of a string changes?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics

I recently did a practical investigation which involved connecting a cart and a mass by a string going through a pulley. The cart was on a supposedly friction-less track and the mass was hanging over the edge of the table, being pulled by gravity. As I added more mass to the end of the string, the acceleration of the cart increased. I thought the rule was that all masses are accelerated at the same rate due to gravity, however, this experiment suggests that the more weight added to the end of the string, the faster the system accelerates. Could someone explain this?

Comment: Absent the string, the mass would accelerate at g.

Comment: Is that your set-up you invented? If not what's the textbook reference.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of something called Atwood’s Machine.

The force is given by the weight of the hanging mass. By itself, that would make it accelerate at g.

But because the other mass is connected by a string and accelerated together, the total inertia is larger, hence the acceleration for that force is smaller than g.

As the hanging mass gets bigger, the cart is a smaller fractional effect. That’s what you see.

The math of this is left to the student...

Answer (score 1):

This can be modeled in a system of equations.  Let the cart have mass M, and the total sum of the masses be m.  Hence, $$Ma=T-F$$ and $$ma=mg-T$$

Since the two are connected, acceleration is the same.  We have $$\frac{T-F}{M}=g-\frac{T}{m}$$

Then, $$T(\frac{1}{M}+\frac{1}{m})=g+\frac{F}{M}$$

The right side is a constant.  Hence, if $m$ increases, then $T$ increases too (if you plot a graph of $m$ and $T$, notice that $T$ increases much more slowly than $m$).

Now, if $T$ increases, then acceleration, which is $\frac{T-F}{M}$ is greater since $F$ and $M$ are constants.

You can also check this with $g-\frac{T}{m}$.  Since $m$ increases faster than $T$, $\frac{T}{m}$ is decreasing, which means acceleration, $g-\frac{T}{m}$ is increasing.  Hence, the cart will accelerate more as more weights are added.

Answer (score 0):

"...the rule was that all masses are accelerated at the same rate due to gravity... " - This is true as the force of gravity is defined by the mathematical product of both attracting masses (F=Gm1m1/r2 where G is the gravitational constant).
You correctly state that  the mass that "was hanging over the edge of the table" is
"being pulled by gravity" as there is attracting accelerating force that acts between the dangling masses and the earth. Intriguingly, the mass of the cart is different as its acceleration, it's free falling,  towards the earth is "blocked", and its acceleration only happens perpendicularly in relation to earths's attracting force.
Generally it can be said that any movement along the horizontal line of a gravitational force (the earth) is "free" - there is no gravitational work to be done by earth's gravitational force; so called "potential energy" does not change.
Reiterating on the dangling masses: counter-intuitively as it may seem, as Galileo did his famous leaning tower of Pisa experiment, which Newton refered to, even if different in weight different masses will reach the earth's ground at the same time. It makes no difference if you add 2 kg more to  weight of 1 kg about to fall as any added weight by the linear law of "m1m2" multiplies the gravitational force it's accelerated by, proportionally to its mass (you may say the weight accelerates "itself"). The law you state is true.

However, the law your question is about refers to "acceleration". If two objects, weights, of 1 or 2 kg reach the same velocity (this is what "accceleration" refers to) they still will attain different momentum. In other words - in spite of travelling to earth with one and the same velocity on their way the 1kg-weight will double its momentum energy, work, force, according to

F=1/2ma.

So you must distinguish velocity from impulse, force and work that does depend on the mass and you must distinguish if one and the same  mass underlies gravity or impulse. (In my opinion you may say that inertial and gravitational mass are different in setups the question refers to, they are not the same, it depends of the context you refer to speaking of equivalence of inertial and gravitational mass.)

This is why your "machine" is able to transfer gravitational power into perpendicular acceleration that thus is not a gravitational acceleration in a strict sense but is literally driven by it. In other words your machine miraculously translates gravitational into "mechanical" work.

Whereas the dangling masses can make use of Newton's law on gravitation the masses of  the cart that move horizontically cannot. They profit from Newton's three basic laws which are completely different - in their realm - from the law of gravitation.